# Twitter api 1.1 get trends by date

Tags: twitter

Twitter api 1.1 trend place only get the trend by today. It that possible I can select a specific date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the API does not allow you that.

You have to get support in a third part that who keeps a record

http://twend.it/ is a good source of historical trends